Natural units without unwelcomed $\pi$
My question is this: Is it possible to create a set of natural units that do not force us to use $\pi$ in the wrong places, as Heaviside had warned?
Among all possible natural units, Planck units are probably the most famous ones, and definitely the simplest ones, as they are normally defined by setting $c = \hbar = G = k_\text{C} = k_\text{B} = 1$:

$l_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}$
$m_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}$
$t_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^5}}$
$q_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{k_\text{C}}} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$
$T_\text{P} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c^5}{G k_\text{B}^2}}$

However, if we are familiar with Oliver Heaviside, by looking at these units we will immediately recall his warnings against considering as “true constants” $G$ and $k_\text{C}$, because these hide a $\pi$ in their definitions and this $\pi$ will sneakily end up embedded in our units – we won't “see” this $\pi$, since a unit is 1 by definition, however we can assume that it is there, especially if $\pi$ starts to pop up in places were it is not expected to appear:

It is not long since it was taken for granted that the common electrical units were correct. That curious and obtrusive constant 4 was considered by some to be a sort of blessed dispensation, without which all electrical theory would fall to pieces. I believe that this view is now nearly extinct, and that it is well recognised that the 4 was an unfortunate and mischievous mistake, the source of many evils.
In plain English, the common system of electrical units involves an irrationality of the same kind as would be brought into the metric system of weights and measures, were we to define the unit area to be the area, not of a square with unit side, but of a circle of unit diameter. The constant  would then obtrude itself into the area of a rectangle, and everywhere it should not be, and be a source of great confusion and inconvenience. So it is in the common electrical units, which are truly irrational.
Now, to make a mistake is easy and natural to man. But that is not enough. The next thing is to correct it: When a mistake has once been started, it is not necessary to go on repeating it for ever and ever with cumulative inconvenience.
― Oliver Heaviside (1893). Electromagnetic Theory, Volume 1, pp. x–xi.

Therefore we immediately take action and get rid of $G$ and $k_\text{C}$, then we put $\frac{1}{4 \pi G}$ and  $\frac{1}{4 \pi k_\text{C}} = \varepsilon_0$ in their places (i.e. we set $c = \hbar = \frac{1}{4 \pi G} = k_\text{C} = \varepsilon_0 = 1$). By doing so we get another famous set of natural (or “Planck”) units, that in which the elementary charge ends up being equal to 0.30286…:

$l_{\text{P}}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi G\hbar}{c^{3}}}$
$m_{\text{P}}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{4\pi G}}$
$t_{\text{P}}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi G\hbar}{c^{5}}}$
$q_{\text{P}}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \hbar c} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}}$
$T_{\text{P}}^{\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c^{5}}{4\pi Gk_{\text{B}}^{2}}}$

Sadly enough, though, now $\pi$ starts to appear in places where we do not expect it, and, for example, the elementary charge has become equal to $e = q_{\text{P}}^{\prime} \sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}$.
Where does that $\pi$ come from?
The most obvious way to get rid of that $\pi$ is by using the Planck constant instead of the reduced Planck constant (i.e. by setting $c = h = \frac{1}{4 \pi G} = k_\text{C} = \varepsilon_0 = 1$).
Doing so will produce this other set of units:

$l_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi G h}{c^{3}}}$
$m_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{h c}{4\pi G}}$
$t_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi G h}{c^{5}}}$
$q_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \sqrt{\varepsilon_0  h c} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}}$
$T_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \sqrt{\frac{h c^{5}}{4\pi Gk_{\text{B}}^{2}}}$

As this yields $q_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}}$, we have reached our goal of getting rid of $\pi$ from our unit.
But isn't $h$, too, a constant that hides a $\pi$ due to geometry, with the “true” fundamental constant being $\hbar$? And in fact, by setting $h = 1$ soon enough we find out that our unit of angular momentum ($\Lambda_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime}$) will be equal to the quantum of angular momentum ($\hbar$) multiplied by $2\pi$ (i.e. $\Lambda_{\text{P}}^{\prime\prime} = 2\pi\hbar$) – again $\pi$ in the wrong place (a ratio between angular momenta).
I just can't seem to be able to create a set of natural units without causing $\pi$ to end up in the wrong places, that “source of many evils”.

I feel this is a valid question, if a little confusingly written. Why should there be a term of $\pi$ if a circle is nowhere to be seen?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

After a long chat, spontaneously born after this answer, with @Travis – whom I want to thank for the patience – I think I am able to answer my own question.
The recipe for making $\pi$ “appear in the right places” in the equations (i.e. just when spheres and circles are present – not just in random places) seems to be the following:

Forget that $h$ ever existed: always use $\hbar$ instead
Forget that $k_\text{C}$ ever existed: always use $\varepsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi k_\text{C}}$ instead
Forget that $G$ ever existed: always use $g_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi G}$ instead
Forget that $\alpha$ ever existed: always use “alphabar” α $= 4\pi\alpha = \frac{e^2}{\varepsilon_0 \hbar c}$ instead (yes, this is a new made-up constant – I want thank @emc for suggesting me the symbol)

I paste here one of my last messages in the chat:

@Travis I think I solved it. Imagine that there is no h, only hbar. Now imagine that there is no alpha, but only alphabar = 4 * pi * alpha. Now rewrite all the known equations: pi will appear only when there are circles or spheres.
Long story short: alpha contains an embedded pi
So the “right” system of units is the one based on hbar. The fact that electric charge contains 4 * pi * alpha is not a problem, because it actually contains only alphabar
You can start from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant. Take all the equations and rewrite them using hbar and alphabar
Heaviside will be proud

Accordingly, at least one of the possible “right” systems of units (i.e. one that makes $\pi$ “appear in the right places”) is this:

$l = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{g_0 c^{3}}}$
$m = \sqrt{g_0 \hbar c}$
$t = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{g_0 c^{5}}}$
$q = \sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \hbar c} = \frac{e}{\sqrt{\text{alphabar}}}$ – see *Note below.
$T = \sqrt{\frac{g_0 \hbar c^{5}}{k_{\text{B}}^{2}}}$

*Note: I apologize for writing “alphabar” verbatim, there isn't yet a LaTeX glyph for α.
I suspect that if we define “alphabar” as $\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha}$ instead of $4\pi\alpha$, elegance in the equations will benefit, but I will have to explore this hypothesis more in depth.

There's a problem with your replacement of the fine structure constant: that constant is properly dimensionless, so its manigitude is physically meaningful. Specifically, each electromagetic vertex in a Feynman diagram is associated with a factor of $\alpha$ in the amplitude. So a "one-loop" virtual particle process has an amplitude that goes like $\alpha^2$, and a "two-loop" process like $\alpha^4$. Electromagnetism is "perturbative" presicely because $\alpha\ll1$. Although there are more two-loop diagrams than one-loop diagrams, the one-loop approximation is useful because $\alpha$ is small.

By contrast, the strong interaction has $\alpha_S\approx 0.1$, so the two-loop processes contribute more to the interaction than do the one-loop processes, and the strong interaction is "nonperturbative." Sticking a factor of $4\pi$ into each term in this expansion is inelegant in just the same way as measuring angles in degrees, once you have discovered the expansions of sine and cosine in terms of sucessive powers of the properly-dimensionless radian.

For two specific examples, consider that the electrostatic potential between two unit charges is $U=\alpha\hbar c/r$, and that the hydrogen atom's binding energy is $13.6\ \mathrm{eV}=\alpha^2 mc^2$, with reduced mass $m=\left(\frac1{m_e}+\frac1{m_p}\right)^{-1}\approx m_\text{electron}$ and one factor of $\alpha$ from the photon vertex with each of the charges.

@rob Thanks for pointing that out. Electromagnetism will for sure remain perturbative with both ways of defining alphabar. At the moment QED goes a bit beyond my safe zone, but I can say that its math is already full of “$\pi$ in the wrong places”, so it is hard to make things worse. The first thing now I will look into is whether $\pi$ might “appear” due to alphabar and then get canceled again by replacing the elementary charge with our charge in the units above (just guessing). Or, if $\pi$ does not go away, I will try to understand if it is geometrically justified. It might require a bit.

Compare to writing $$\sin x = \left(\frac{2\pi x}{360^\circ}\right) - \frac1{3!} \left(\frac{2\pi x}{360^\circ}\right)^3 + \frac1{5!} \left(\frac{2\pi x}{360^\circ}\right)^5 -\cdots $$ if you use ridiculous Babylonian "degrees" to measure circular arcs. We did it that way for thousands of years before calculus led to the discovery of a "natural" unit for trigonometry.

@rob But my efforts go exactly in the direction of adding elegance and simplicity to the equations. It is possible that QED – which is already full of $\pi$ and complicate math – will have one additional $\pi$ by using alphabar; but if that is the price for simplifying and rationalizing all other equations in physics, then I believe that it is more than worth it.

so @rob and moon, I was also sorta ranting about this "rationalized Planck units" before in this thread.  To me, it's important that Natural Units not use any prototype object but are based only on normalizing properties of free space.  So Planck Units.  But they should be rationalized.  That way, for both E&M and gravitational waves, both the speed of propagation $c$ and the characteristic impedance of radiation in free space is normalized to 1.

The constant $\pi$ is a number which "falls" quite naturally out of all sort of abstract mathematical calculations.  The claim that it is "unnatural" to see it in physical formula is really the problem.
I am reminded of a moment in Terry Pratchett's novel Pyramids where a (somewhat inebriated) geometer complains that the ratio of the circumference of a circle to it's diameter is wrong because he feels it should be a whole number, not some weird number with no end of digits.
It is a human conceit to expect formula to fit our expectations.  The universe, on the other hand, doesn't care what we expect.
On the other hand, units are essentially arbitrary.  We can produce any numerical set of unit values we like.  All we require is that a system of units is self-consistent and reproducible.

Where does that $\pi$ come from?

We developed our current "favorite" systems of units from historical formula and definitions that did not reflect our current understanding.
This is why we now use units based on a "better" understanding of the measurement and definition process, but in doing that we're also trying to maintain a sort of "backward compatibility" with the previous units (because e.g. a kilo can't suddenly be declared radically different, we use it in too many practical ways).
The Unit Sphere and that Gauss chap.
More particularly, factors of $4\pi$ typically turn up when we are integrating over a sphere's area, which is something we do rather a lot in any formula involving fluxes, charges, masses and forces associated with them.  This is historically how we developed our sets of formulas which led to theories which we evolved our units from.  If you've got a three dimensional space, it's hard to avoid formulas with factors like $4\pi$ popping up one you start applying Gauss's Law.

I just can't seem to be able to create a set of natural units without causing $\pi$ to end up in the wrong places, that “source of many evils”.

"Wrong" is an aesthetic opinion.  From a mathematical point of view, it doesn't matter.

This is sort of the correct answer - "wrong" is indeed just aesthetic. We can set whatever constants to whatever we like (bar $\pi$ and $e$).

As this answer got voted, I must explain why it is not a good answer. I am not asking whether people should like $\pi$ or not, I am asking: Is it possible, theoretically, to create a system of units so that the physical equations will show $\pi$ only when spheres or circles are involved? When physicists started using $\varepsilon_0$ instead of $k_\text{C}$, they did it so that $\pi$ would appear only in the presence of spheres or circles. Is it possible to build a system of units with the same goal? After creating it we can like it or hate it, but is it possible, mathematically speaking?

Where $\pi$ is supposed to go, is a highly opinionated issue that people can get into serious fights about.
But it is trivial to see that it should be taken as $c=1=e=k_B$ rather than having something else; I mean, we count the number of charges.
All the momentum integrals that appear as $\int\dfrac{\mathrm d^3\vec p}{(2\pi\hslash)^3}$ are really trying to hint to you that it is $h=1$ that is natural. This way, the exponential factors really should appear as $\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ipx}$, as the mathematicians like it. Replace $\varepsilon_0$ with the fine structure constant $\alpha$ and you can make it such that no constant appear anywhere in Maxwell's equations, just like in Heaviside-Lorentz units as is common in High Energy Physics literature. Note that $h=1$ implies that $[p,x]=\frac1{2\pi\mathrm i}$ and this is sensible; Terence Tao asserted that it is not $\pi$ or $\tau=2\pi$ that is fundamental, because it is $2\pi\mathrm i$ that always appears together.
As for the masses, one can pick either the Dalton or the electron mass to be set to one. There is a preference for the electron mass, because there are many situations whereby the electron has gone relativistic without the ions also going relativistic. This makes it convenient whenever you want to implement code with SR electrons and NR ions. With the set $c=1=e=k_B=h=m_e$, you would have a complete set, and then everything becomes dimensionless.

I also answered that portion. If you choose as I did, every appearance of $\pi$ will go as where it should go, at least as far as I can make it physically and mathematically pleasing.

The question is not about the most convenient system of units. The point is whether we can create a system of units that generates equations in which $\pi$ appears in the right places (a.k.a. places in which spheres or circles are somehow present or lurking in the background). Furthermore, choosing the mass of the electron as the unit for the mass, as you just did, will force arbitrary constants into the system (specifically, in your system, to know the value of G you will have to know the ratio between the mass of the electron and one Stoney mass).

If I am not wrong in your system of units $\pi$ will disappear from Coulomb's law, where instead it should appear.

As for G, no practical unit system can choose G to be a defining constant, because we know it to so few digits of accuracy. When you start arguing about these details, you will realise that, e.g. the ratio of mass of electron to Stoney mass, is exactly what is physical about all these things.

No, as I said, all constants disappear from Maxwell's equations, which means that $\pi$ goes into Coulomb's law, as is normal in rationalised units.

Also, you should have just looked up Heaviside-Lorentz units. It is the norm in HEP. It is very clear that $4\pi$ belongs to Coulomb's law.

One can easily argue that $h$ does not hide any $\pi$, because it is merely the energy of a photon divided by its frequency.  No $\pi$ to be found.  So if that is your goal, you can achieve it with $h = 1$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Planck's constant comes in two flavors: h, and h/(2*pi). Each has its uses, and no one seems to be too much bothered by this state of affairs.
By the way, frequency can be expressed as revolutions per second with one cycle being equal to (2*pi) radians, so pi can indeed creep in there.
